# Why am I getting this Stack Overflow exception?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, tetris

I am writing a Tetris clone, which is the largest project I have really done. In implementing the row deletion code, I have begun recieving a stack overflow exception. I think it probably has something to do with my huge collections or horribly inefficient use of Linq. Here is the specific method that is causing the issue:

```
void MoveAllAboveDown(int row)
    {
        List<Block> newBlockList = new List<Block>();
        for (int rowCheck = row; rowCheck > _VertOffset; --rowCheck)
        {
            for (int i = _HorizOffset; i < _HorizOffset + _Width; ++i)
            {
                //If the spot above this is filled
                if (_blockList.Where(block => block.Contains(new Vector2(i, rowCheck - 1))).ToList().Count > 0)
                {
                    //insert block here
                    newBlockList.Add(new Block(new Vector2(i, rowCheck), new[,] { { true } }, Color.Black, _texture));
                }
                else
                {
                    var list = _blockList.Where(tempBlock => tempBlock.Contains(new Vector2(i, rowCheck - 1))).ToList();
                    if (list.Count > 0)
                        list.ElementAt(0).Delete(new Vector2(i, rowCheck - 1));
                }
            }
        }
        for (int rowToDelete = row; rowToDelete > _VertOffset; --rowToDelete)
        {
            DeleteRow(rowToDelete);
        }
        foreach (Block block in newBlockList)
        {
            _blockList.Add(block);
        }
    }
```

I'll attach the entire source if I can figure out how (even using a separate site if I have to).

If you feel like it, I really wouldn't mind if someone were to look at the entire code base and tell me what I do write and wrong (like naming conventions, algorithms, etc.). Obviously this is not what the site is for, but I figured I'd throw this in since I am attacking the code base anyway.

Edit: 
Here is the main game file:
http://pastebin.com/PqVAS56U
Here is the rest of the code:
http://pastebin.com/JjBKZgwN

Edit2:
I believe this is a stack trace:

```
'Tetris.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Tetris.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\OldComp\Users\patrick\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Tetris\Tetris\Tetris\bin\x86\Debug\Tetris.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Tetris.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game\v4.0_4.0.0.0__842cf8be1de50553\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll'
'Tetris.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__842cf8be1de50553\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll'
'Tetris.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Xna.Framework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__842cf8be1de50553\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll'
'Tetris.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch\v4.0_4.0.0.0__842cf8be1de50553\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch.dll'
'Tetris.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Tetris.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Tetris.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Tetris.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__842cf8be1de50553\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.dll'
'Tetris.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
The program '[7484] Tetris.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Post the  stack trace (well... enough of it so that we get the idea).

Comment: Show us the stack trace when you get the overflow. Usually stack overflow is a result of infinite recursion.

Comment: I suspect he is calling MoveAllAboveDown() down in DeleteRow()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see you decrementing the value of `row` that you are passing to `MoveAllAboveDown()` and then into `DeleteRow()`. Your `DeleteRow()` function again calls `MoveAllAboveDown()` with same `row` number.

So they will keep on calling each other until StackOverflow.

Comment: I figured out what you mean here now. I feel dumb for misinterpreting what you were trying to tell me the first time I read it.

Comment: I think the last line, that I added now, makes more sense

Answer (score 5):

Without tracing the rest of the code, I suspect part of it is the use of `row` instead of `rowToDelete` in:

```
for (int rowToDelete = row; rowToDelete > _VertOffset; --rowToDelete)
{
    // DeleteRow(row); // Woops! Typo
    DeleteRow(rowToDelete);
}
```

Edit: If not there, then it is likely in DeleteRow.

Comment: Wow, good catch. Unfortunately, I am still getting the stack overflow. I'll get the stack trace in a second.

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason you're getting a stack trace, is that MoveAllAboveDown(int row) calls DeleteRow(int row) which calls MoveAllAboveDown(int row) creating an infinite loop, as pointed out already [by cornerback84](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882690/why-am-i-getting-this-stack-overflow-exception/7882828#7882828).

Here's a couple of other tips:

- What you edited into the question was not the *stack trace*, but the *trace output*.

  - *Stack trace* means a print out of the *call stack*, which will show the nested currently executing methods.
  - To view the call stack select Debug > Windows > Call Stack, in the Visual Studio menu.
  - To copy the call stack for pasting into questions, click on "Copy exception details" in the [Exception Assistant Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ww37f14.aspx)
- Since you asked for comment on naming conventions etc., I'd recommend checking out:

  - [Microsoft Naming Guidlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28VS.71%29.aspx)
  - [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) (this is excellent!)
  - As a bonus tip, check out [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28VS.80%29.aspx) too - you will learn lots, guaranteed :)

Comment: Thank you for this. You are correct. That is what the problem was. I was thinking that the trace output didn't look quite like a stack trace, but I couldn't figure out how to get the stack trace. Thank you for both of those "other tips." Posting the real stack trace seems like wasted effort now, though. Thank you for this response, it is most helpful. I would accept it, but that doesn't seem fair to cornerback84 who beat you to it.

Comment: Yeah, no worries. I saw the other answer would likely solve your problem already, and only posted to offer the tips.